# How to create each page in each js files (react-native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to create each page in each js files (react-native)?
How to include second page in this construction? Or how should I need to include?

```
var SecondPage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
      );
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on what kind of functionality you are trying to achieve here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is exporting your react component so it can be used in other js files.

Put your second page code in a separated file, for example: secondPage.js. This file would look somthing like this:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var SecondPage = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
        );
    },
});

module.exports = SecondPage;
```

To use your component just import it using require. (and don't forget to set the correct path to the new script file):

```
var React = require('react-native');
var SecondPage = require('./path_to_script/SecondPage');

var {
  AppRegistry,
} = React;

var MyApp = React.createClass({

     render: function() {
        return (
          <SecondPage />
        );
     },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```